# <li>-element in same line as previous text

Tags: html, css

I am working on a HTML logfile where it should be possible to collapse specific items (such as exceptions). Therefore I use an unorderd list with some li elements. Unfortunately I can't display the first li element inline with the previous text (the timestamp in my example):

[image]

I have uploaded a JSFiddle for this: https://jsfiddle.net/rs358vw8/

```
<div class="debug">
    <span class="timestamp">[09:33:04.137] </span>
    <span class="message">
        <ul class="tree">
            <li><a href="#" class="exception">Exception message</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="exception">Innereception</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="exception">Stacktrace</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="exception">Bla</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </span>
    <br>        
</div>
```

How can I display the first li element inline with my timestamp / text?

Comment: What is the desired desigb you are looking for?

Comment: `ul` elements are, by default, `display:block` elements (IIRC) - you need to add a rule to your CSS along the lines of `.tree{display:inline;}` to make it display in-line with the `span`s elements

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the HTML is invalid and may be the cause of the issue. A `<ul>` element may not be the child of a `<span>` element.

Comment: @connexo The HTML is invalid. Run it through the validator. A span element may only contain phrasing content. A `<ul>` is not phrasing content.

Comment: @Rob what do you suggest to use instead there?

Comment: Why aren't you using a `<div>`?

Comment: @Rob because I thought using span is the right thing for "inline text". If div is more convenient here because of the ul inside it, I will change this. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: A span is for inline text but a `<ul>` element is a list, not "phrasing content" and is not inline. https://developers.whatwg.org/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this CSS for your `ul` element, making it an `inline-block` with vertical-alignment at the top of the line:

```
ul.tree {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sd25muvn/1/

Answer (score 3):

Here is a forked update of your JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fzLosb0h/

I added two lines to `.timestamp`:

```
.timestamp {
    color: #999 !important;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 5px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use display:flex

```js
  var tree = document.querySelectorAll('ul.tree a:not(:last-child)');
  for(var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++){
   tree[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var parent = e.target.parentElement;
    var classList = parent.classList;
    if(classList.contains("open")) {
     classList.remove('open');
     var opensubs = parent.querySelectorAll(':scope .open');
     for(var i = 0; i < opensubs.length; i++){
      opensubs[i].classList.remove('open');
     }
    } else {
     classList.add('open');
    }
   });
  }
```

```css
body {
    background: #222;
    font-family: Consolas;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.debug{
  display:flex;
}
.timestamp {
    color: #999 !important;
}

.message {
    color: #6abaf5 !important;
}

.debug {
 opacity: 0.7 !important;
}

.exception {
    color:red !important;
 font-weight: bold !important;
}

.exception .stack {
 color: #ff0000 !important;
}


/* Collapsible Tree */
ul.tree {
 display: flex;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

ul.tree li {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}

ul.tree li ul {
    display: none;
}

ul.tree li.open > ul {
    display: block;
}

ul.tree li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.tree li a:before {
    height: 1em;
    padding:0 .1em;
    font-size: .8em;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1.3em;
    top: .2em;
}

ul.tree li > a:not(:last-child):before {
    content: '+';
}

ul.tree li.open > a:not(:last-child):before {
    content: '-';
}
```

```html
 <div class="debug">
  <span class="timestamp">[09:33:04.137] </span>
  <span class="message">
   <ul class="tree">
    <li><a href="#" class="exception">Exception message</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="exception">Innereception</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="exception">Stacktrace</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="exception">Bla</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </span>
  <br>  
 </div>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Add a `display:inline` rule like this (you may need to adjust the padding, margins, etc. to suit your elements):

```
ul.tree, ul.tree > li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

**See demo below**

```js
var tree = document.querySelectorAll('ul.tree a:not(:last-child)');
for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
  tree[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var parent = e.target.parentElement;
    var classList = parent.classList;
    if (classList.contains("open")) {
      classList.remove('open');
      var opensubs = parent.querySelectorAll(':scope .open');
      for (var i = 0; i < opensubs.length; i++) {
        opensubs[i].classList.remove('open');
      }
    } else {
      classList.add('open');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #222;
  font-family: Consolas;
  font-size: 11px;
}
.timestamp {
  color: #999 !important;
}
.message {
  color: #6abaf5 !important;
}
.debug {
  opacity: 0.7 !important;
}
.exception {
  color: #ff0000 !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
}
.exception .stack {
  color: #ff0000 !important;
}
/* Collapsible Tree */

ul.tree, ul.tree > li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
ul.tree li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}
ul.tree li ul {
  display: none;
}
ul.tree li.open > ul {
  display: block;
}
ul.tree li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul.tree li a:before {
  height: 1em;
  padding: 0 .1em;
  font-size: .8em;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.3em;
  top: .2em;
}
ul.tree li > a:not(:last-child):before {
  content: '+';
}
ul.tree li.open > a:not(:last-child):before {
  content: '-';
}
```

```html
<div class="debug">
  <span class="timestamp">[09:33:04.137] </span>
  <span class="message">
        <ul class="tree">
            <li><a href="#" class="exception">Exception message</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="exception">Innereception</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="exception">Stacktrace</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="exception">Bla</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </span>
  <br>
</div>
```